# Call to a member function where() on integer

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error:

> Call to a member function where() on integer

when I run this code:

```php
DB::table('level_one_models')
  ->increment('followers', 1)
  ->where('active', '=', 1);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Call `where` before `increment`:

```php
DB::table('level_one_models')
  ->where('active', 1)
  ->increment('followers', 1);
```

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webemplo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35